# AutoFS wildcard subdirectory

Tags: nfs, mount, autofs

I am trying to automount `/home/users/<username>/secure` for all users using AutoFS.

Naturally I would put down this line as a direct map:

```
/home/users/*/secure -fstype=nfs4,rw,sec=krb5p jupiter:/home/users/&
```

However according the [documentation](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01_ws_BI&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.rst_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c02153184-4%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.rid_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=docDisplayResURL&ac.admitted=1387056877535.876444892.492883150):

> You cannot use the asterisk (*) wildcard in a direct map.

If I wanted to mount the entire home directory this would be easily done in an indirect map as follows:

```
* -fstype=nfs4,rw,sec=krb5p jupiter:/home/users/&
```

And the master file would have:

```
/home/users /etc/auto.home
```

But it seems that once I want to target a sub-directory of the wildcard, it is not really supported. At least I cannot find the right documentation for it.

Another way in which I was hoping to achieve this, is with an executable map, but it is unclear to me what the executable map should do for all the directories in `/home/users/<username>/` other than secure. How should it signal that nothing should be mounted for those paths?

Currently I am using pam_mount to achieve this. However these are mobile workstations, that have intermittent access to the NFS server. With pam_mount, when the user logs in while the server is not accessible, the secure directory will not be mounted until logs out and logs in again. So therefore I am hoping autofs will be better.